# How do I prevent users from removing display:none in source code?

Tags: php, hide

With some if/else PHP statement, I can show or hide some divs depending on if the profile page being checked out by a user belongs to that user or not.

For instance,

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
if ($uid == $id)
{
?>
<div id="block_user"></div>
<?php }
else { ?>
<div id="block_user" style="display:none"></div>
<?php
}  ?>
```

The issue is even if the profile I'm checking out doesn't belong to me, if I **inspect the element** with Google webmaster tool, and **remove**

```
style="display:none"
```

the div **becomes visible again.**

How could I prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove the `else` part

```
<?php
if ($uid == $id) {
?>
<div id="block_user"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I will, i have to wait 10 minutes though

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide stuff for real you have to dynamically create it within the PHP code... Such as :

```
<php

    if ($uid == $id){
     echo '<div id="block_user"></div>';
    }

?>
```

which I guess you already are doing but simply dont print it out if you dont want to show it.

Answer (score 1):

instead of hiding the div, remove the div element which you don't want to show.

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
if ($uid == $id)
 {
  ?>
  <div id="block_user"></div>
<?php } ?>
```